# Why does my program ask for a symbol 2 times instead of one(ignores first symbol)?

Tags: java, user-input

This is simple Hangman game:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] words = {"writer", "that", "program"};
    int wordNumber = (int) (Math.random() * words.length);

    System.out.print("Enter a letter in word ");
    for (int i = 0; i < words[wordNumber].length(); i++)
        System.out.print('*');
    System.out.print(" > ");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char letter;
    do {
        letter = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
        boolean asterisksInWord = false;
        String[] discoveredElements = new String[words[wordNumber].length()];
        int countOfTries = 0;
        int arrayCount = 0;
        int asteriskCount = 0;
        System.out.print("Enter a letter in word ");
        do {
            asterisksInWord = false;
            boolean contain;
            if (asteriskCount != 1) {
                asteriskCount = 0;
                for (char item : words[wordNumber].toCharArray()) {
                    contain = Arrays.asList(discoveredElements).contains(String.valueOf(item));
                    if (contain) {
                        System.out.print(item);
                    } else if (item == letter) {
                        System.out.print(item);
                        discoveredElements[arrayCount] = String.valueOf(item);
                        arrayCount++;
                    } else {
                        System.out.print('*');
                        asterisksInWord = true;
                        asteriskCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (asterisksInWord) {
                System.out.print(" > ");
                letter = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
                if (asteriskCount != 1)
                    System.out.print("Enter a letter in word ");
            } else
                System.out.println("The word is " + words[wordNumber] +
                    " You missed " + (countOfTries + 2 - words[wordNumber].length()) + " time(s)");
            countOfTries++;
        } while (asterisksInWord);
        System.out.print("Do you want to guess another word? Enter y or n >");
    } while (input.nextLine().charAt(0) == 'y');
}
```

The log of it's run is

```
Enter a letter in word **** > t
Enter a letter in word t**t > h
Enter a letter in word th*t > a
The word is that You missed 0 time(s)
Do you want to guess another word? Enter y or n >y
y
Enter a letter in word **** >
```

My question is why does it ignores first symbol 'y' when asking "Do you want to guess another word?".

I'tried to create some test programs with same do-while conditions but they don't ask for character 2 times like that program.

Comment: I suggest you to read characters using chat `ch = (char) System.in.read();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program asks for your input two times, because you have programmed it like that. After printing - `"Do you want to guess another word? Enter y or n >"` - you do `input.nextLine()` inside the while condition as well as as the first statement after `do` , so it asks for input twice.

Maybe you can move the question `Enter the letter in the word` to the inner `do` loop instead of doing that in the `if` condition `if (asterisksInWord) {` .

Also, according to your current logic, it does not ignore your first symbol, that is the real one that decides whether to exit the loop or not, the next input is actually your first guess.